# Difference in days between two dates in Java?

Tags: java, jodatime, datediff

I need to find the **number of days between two dates**: one is from a report and one is the current date. My snippet:

```
  int age=calculateDifference(agingDate, today);
```

Here `calculateDifference` is a private method, `agingDate` and `today` are `Date` objects, just for your clarification. I've followed two articles from a Java forum, [Thread 1](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=1714945#1714945) / [Thread 2](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=2292039#2292039).

It works fine in a standalone program although when I include this into my logic to read from the report I get an unusual difference in values.

Why is it happening and how can I fix it?

**EDIT :**

I'm getting a greater number of days compared to the actual amount of Days.

```
public static int calculateDifference(Date a, Date b)
{
    int tempDifference = 0;
    int difference = 0;
    Calendar earlier = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar later = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (a.compareTo(b) < 0)
    {
        earlier.setTime(a);
        later.setTime(b);
    }
    else
    {
        earlier.setTime(b);
        later.setTime(a);
    }

    while (earlier.get(Calendar.YEAR) != later.get(Calendar.YEAR))
    {
        tempDifference = 365 * (later.get(Calendar.YEAR) - earlier.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        difference += tempDifference;

        earlier.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, tempDifference);
    }

    if (earlier.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) != later.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR))
    {
        tempDifference = later.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) - earlier.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        difference += tempDifference;

        earlier.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, tempDifference);
    }

    return difference;
}
```

**Note :**

Unfortunately, none of the answers helped me solve the problem. I've accomplished [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329469/difference-in-days-between-two-java-dates) with the help of [Joda-time](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joda-time/files/joda-time/) library.

Comment: What do you mean by unusual difference values? Could you be more explicit please, or give an example of some sort?

Comment: Can you post the code for calculateDifference method?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`,
 `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Likewise, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

I would suggest you use the excellent [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library instead of the flawed java.util.Date and friends.  You could simply write

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

Date past = new Date(110, 5, 20); // June 20th, 2010
Date today = new Date(110, 6, 24); // July 24th 
int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays(); // => 34
```

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/faq.html#datediff -- I was about to suggest same thing.

Comment: @Adam - I've Date objects, but in Joda Time API, daysBetween method takes ReadableInstant as parameter. Can u tell me how can I do it? I've no idea on those APIs. Thanx

Comment: jodaInstance = new DateTime(jdkDate);

On conversion between joda time and java.util.Date and friends, see http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#JDK_Interoperability

Comment: @Adam - I've tried, but getting greater value. Say for agingDate="06/22/2010", today="07/23/2010", it gives 182 days as difference.. Can you pls tell me what's going wrong???

Comment: @ven coder - I think you can post it as a separate question about using joda time.  You could also provide a code snippet that gave the seemingly wrong result.

Comment: @Adam - Then what about this question. You're telling me to ask two questions for a single problem?? Help me resolve this issue...

Comment: @ven coder - I updated the sample code, it works for me.  I see this question answered.  Show the code that doesn't work for you, either here, or in a separate question.

Comment: +1 for joda time; -1 for not mentioning that this solution in fact has two dependencies (joda-time + joda-convert).

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 48):

I might be too late to join the game but what the heck huh? :)

Do you think this is a threading issue? How are you using the output of this method for example? OR

Can we change your code to do something as simple as:

```
Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(<your earlier date>);
    calendar2.set(<your current date>);
    long milliseconds1 = calendar1.getTimeInMillis();
    long milliseconds2 = calendar2.getTimeInMillis();
    long diff = milliseconds2 - milliseconds1;
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000);
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000);
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    System.out.println("\nThe Date Different Example");
    System.out.println("Time in milliseconds: " + diff
 + " milliseconds.");
    System.out.println("Time in seconds: " + diffSeconds
 + " seconds.");
    System.out.println("Time in minutes: " + diffMinutes 
+ " minutes.");
    System.out.println("Time in hours: " + diffHours 
+ " hours.");
    System.out.println("Time in days: " + diffDays 
+ " days.");
  }
```

Comment: This code doesn't pay attention for daylight saving time, so the result of the difference in days might not be correct.

Comment: @Johanna Though it's pretty late, can you please give an example when this fails. I've tried a lot but couldn't find any date ranges for which this fails. Thank you.

Comment: This error only happens if you're in a timezone (your local timezone setting) which uses daylight saving time, for example Central European Time, Berlin, Paris or Amsterdam. The start and end day of daylight saving time don't have 24 hours, for example the 30th March 2014 only had 23 hours while the 26th October 2014 will have 25 hours. If the earlier date is before 30th March 2:00 and the later date is after 30th March 3:00 then the calculation fails.

Answer (score 23):

The diff / (24 * etc) does not take Timezone into account, so if your default timezone has a DST in it, it can throw the calculation off.

This [link](http://tripoverit.blogspot.com/2007/07/java-calculate-difference-between-two.html) has a nice little implementation.

Here is the source of the above link in case the link goes down:

```
/** Using Calendar - THE CORRECT WAY**/  
public static long daysBetween(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {  
  //assert: startDate must be before endDate  
  Calendar date = (Calendar) startDate.clone();  
  long daysBetween = 0;  
  while (date.before(endDate)) {  
    date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);  
    daysBetween++;  
  }  
  return daysBetween;  
}
```

and

```
/** Using Calendar - THE CORRECT (& Faster) WAY**/  
public static long daysBetween(final Calendar startDate, final Calendar endDate)
{
  //assert: startDate must be before endDate  
  int MILLIS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;  
  long endInstant = endDate.getTimeInMillis();  
  int presumedDays = 
    (int) ((endInstant - startDate.getTimeInMillis()) / MILLIS_IN_DAY);  
  Calendar cursor = (Calendar) startDate.clone();  
  cursor.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, presumedDays);  
  long instant = cursor.getTimeInMillis();  
  if (instant == endInstant)  
    return presumedDays;

  final int step = instant < endInstant ? 1 : -1;  
  do {  
    cursor.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, step);  
    presumedDays += step;  
  } while (cursor.getTimeInMillis() != endInstant);  
  return presumedDays;  
}
```

Comment: The second method is wrong, the final `while` should be. `while (cursor.getTimeInMillis() <= endInstant); ` Otherwise you get an infinite loop if less than an day out.

Comment: From comment in the link

"You should be aware that the algorithm given may give 'one more day' than you expect.

It gives 1 as the number of days between 2009-02-28 19:00:00 and 2009-02-28 19:00:01."

Answer (score 16):

## java.time

In Java 8 and later, use the [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)).

### `Duration`

The [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class represents a span of time as a number of seconds plus a fractional second. It can count days, hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime oldDate = now.minusDays(1).minusMinutes(10);
Duration duration = Duration.between(oldDate, now);
System.out.println(duration.toDays());
```

### `ChronoUnit`

If all you need is the number of days, alternatively you can use the [`ChronoUnit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Notice the calculation methods return a `long` rather than `int`.

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( then, now );
```

Comment: also be sure to pass the dates to ChronoUnit.DAYS.between in correct order, else it will return -ve result

Answer (score 13):

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static long calculateDays(String startDate, String endDate)
    {
        Date sDate = new Date(startDate);
        Date eDate = new Date(endDate);
        Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal3.setTime(sDate);
        Calendar cal4 = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal4.setTime(eDate);
        return daysBetween(cal3, cal4);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(calculateDays("2012/03/31", "2012/06/17"));

    }

    /** Using Calendar - THE CORRECT WAY**/
    public static long daysBetween(Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
        Calendar date = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
        long daysBetween = 0;
        while (date.before(endDate)) {
            date.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            daysBetween++;
        }
        return daysBetween;
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop is not excellent idea. How about performance when there are more simple options to do same?

Comment: A performance improvement would be to increment by powers of 2, and then when the condition date.before(endDate) is false, return to the previous iteration and reset the incrementor to 1.  That is so if you are a billion days away, you would do maybe 30 something iterations instead of a billion.  You could also improve performance by making a guess by checking the milliseconds, but that would be less elegant probably.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what you define as the difference. To compare two dates at midnight you can do.

```
long day1 = ...; // in milliseconds.
long day2 = ...; // in milliseconds.
long days = (day2 - day1) / 86400000;
```

Comment: This code doesn't pay attention for daylight saving time, so the result might not be correct.

Comment: @Johanna This solution works with DST. When round is apply after division, this difference is ignored and the result is ok.

Comment: @angelcervera Most of the time it will be correct, but if it is close, the extra hour could make the accuracy +/- 1 day off (i.e. it would round the wrong way).

Comment: @Muhd Yes, You're right. The third line must be:
long days = Math.round( (day2 - day1) / 86400000D );
It's very important that the divisor was a double value.

Comment: This answer doesn't take into account dates before 1970. Calculate how many days old your grandparents are.

Comment: @Snekse Days before 1970 worked exactly the same as after 1970. Can you give me an example?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to plug in my first grade math module into my brain this morning. I was thinking subtracting a negative would throw off the calculation.  We should be able to downvote comments.

Answer (score 9):

Solution using difference between milliseconds time, with correct rounding for DST dates:

```
public static long daysDiff(Date from, Date to) {
    return daysDiff(from.getTime(), to.getTime());
}

public static long daysDiff(long from, long to) {
    return Math.round( (to - from) / 86400000D ); // 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
}
```

One note: Of course, dates must be in some timezone.

The important code:

```
Math.round( (to - from) / 86400000D )
```

If you don't want round, you can use UTC dates,

Comment: @marcolopes No, returns 32. System.out.println(daysDiff(new Date(2014, 2, 1), new Date(2014, 3, 2))); Be careful, because January is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Illustration of the problem: (My code is computing delta in weeks, but same issue applies with delta in days)

Here is a very reasonable-looking implementation:

```
public static final long MILLIS_PER_WEEK = 7L * 24L * 60L * 60L * 1000L;

static public int getDeltaInWeeks(Date latterDate, Date earlierDate) {
    long deltaInMillis = latterDate.getTime() - earlierDate.getTime();
    int deltaInWeeks = (int)(deltaInMillis / MILLIS_PER_WEEK);
    return deltaInWeeks; 
}
```

But this test will fail:

```
public void testGetDeltaInWeeks() {
    delta = AggregatedData.getDeltaInWeeks(dateMar09, dateFeb23);
    assertEquals("weeks between Feb23 and Mar09", 2, delta);
}
```

The reason is:

> Mon Mar 09 00:00:00 EDT 2009 = 1,236,571,200,000
>  Mon Feb 23
>   00:00:00 EST 2009 = 1,235,365,200,000
>  MillisPerWeek =
>   604,800,000
>  Thus,
>  (Mar09 - Feb23) / MillisPerWeek =
>   1,206,000,000 / 604,800,000 = 1.994...

but anyone looking at a calendar would agree that the answer is 2.

Comment: Notice **EDT** and **EST**.  You are a looking at daylight savings time.  168 hours in a week (+1 for "gaining" an hour in the spring) * two weeks, adding in the extra DST hour, and you have: 335 / 168 = 1.9940476190.

Answer (score 3):

I use this funcion:

```
DATEDIFF("31/01/2016", "01/03/2016") // me return 30 days
```

my function:

```
import java.util.Date;

public long DATEDIFF(String date1, String date2) {
        long MILLISECS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
        long days = 0l;
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

        Date dateIni = null;
        Date dateFin = null;        
        try {       
            dateIni = (Date) format.parse(date1);
            dateFin = (Date) format.parse(date2);
            days = (dateFin.getTime() - dateIni.getTime())/MILLISECS_PER_DAY;                        
        } catch (Exception e) {  e.printStackTrace();  }   

        return days; 
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the *[getFragmentInDays](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html#line.1392)* methods in this apache commons-lang class `DateUtils`.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Mad_Troll's answer, I developed this method.

I've run about 30 test cases against it, is the only method that handles sub day time fragments correctly.

Example: If you pass now & now + 1 millisecond that is still the same day.
Doing `1-1-13 23:59:59.098` to `1-1-13 23:59:59.099` returns 0 days, correctly; allot of the other methods posted here will not do this correctly.

Worth noting it does not care about which way you put them in, If your end date is before your start date it will count backwards.

```
/**
 * This is not quick but if only doing a few days backwards/forwards then it is very accurate.
 *
 * @param startDate from
 * @param endDate   to
 * @return day count between the two dates, this can be negative if startDate is after endDate
 */
public static long daysBetween(@NotNull final Calendar startDate, @NotNull final Calendar endDate) {

    //Forwards or backwards?
    final boolean forward = startDate.before(endDate);
    // Which direction are we going
    final int multiplier = forward ? 1 : -1;

    // The date we are going to move.
    final Calendar date = (Calendar) startDate.clone();

    // Result
    long daysBetween = 0;

    // Start at millis (then bump up until we go back a day)
    int fieldAccuracy = 4;
    int field;
    int dayBefore, dayAfter;
    while (forward && date.before(endDate) || !forward && endDate.before(date)) {
        // We start moving slowly if no change then we decrease accuracy.
        switch (fieldAccuracy) {
            case 4:
                field = Calendar.MILLISECOND;
                break;
            case 3:
                field = Calendar.SECOND;
                break;
            case 2:
                field = Calendar.MINUTE;
                break;
            case 1:
                field = Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY;
                break;
            default:
            case 0:
                field = Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH;
                break;
        }
        // Get the day before we move the time, Change, then get the day after.
        dayBefore = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        date.add(field, multiplier);
        dayAfter = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // This shifts lining up the dates, one field at a time.
        if (dayBefore == dayAfter && date.get(field) == endDate.get(field))
            fieldAccuracy--;
        // If day has changed after moving at any accuracy level we bump the day counter.
        if (dayBefore != dayAfter) {
            daysBetween += multiplier;
        }
    }
    return daysBetween;
}
```

*You can remove the `@NotNull` annotations, these are used by Intellij to do code analysis on the fly*

Comment: I take into account Millis, that calculator does not, I'm assuming it rounds down the numbers to 0. As I stated in the top of the answer. Flatten your hours/minutes/seconds/millis and you will find that it will then count correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You say it "works fine in a standalone program," but that you get "unusual difference values" when you "include this into my logic to read from report".  That suggests that your report has some values for which it doesn't work correctly, and your standalone program doesn't have those values.  Instead of a standalone program, I suggest a test case.  Write a test case much as you would a standalone program, subclassing from JUnit's TestCase class.  Now you can run a very specific example, knowing what value you expect (and don't give it today for the test value, because today changes over time).  If you put in the values you used in the standalone program, your tests will probably pass.  That's great - you want those cases to keep working.  Now, add a value from your report, one that doesn't work right.  Your new test will probably fail.  Figure out why it's failing, fix it, and get to green (all tests passing).  Run your report.  See what's still broken; write a test; make it pass.  Pretty soon you'll find your report is working.

Answer (score 1):

Hundred lines of code for this basic function???

Just a simple method:

```
protected static int calculateDayDifference(Date dateAfter, Date dateBefore){
    return (int)(dateAfter.getTime()-dateBefore.getTime())/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24); 
    // MILLIS_IN_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
}
```

Comment: Ignores time zones. Ignores Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies. Ignores rounding of partial days.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getDifferenceIndays(long timestamp1, long timestamp2) {
    final int SECONDS = 60;
    final int MINUTES = 60;
    final int HOURS = 24;
    final int MILLIES = 1000;
    long temp;
    if (timestamp1 < timestamp2) {
        temp = timestamp1;
        timestamp1 = timestamp2;
        timestamp2 = temp;
    }
    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());
    endDate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp1);
    startDate.setTimeInMillis(timestamp2);
    if ((timestamp1 - timestamp2) < 1 * HOURS * MINUTES * SECONDS * MILLIES) {
        int day1 = endDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int day2 = startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (day1 == day2) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    int diffDays = 0;
    startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, diffDays);
    while (startDate.before(endDate)) {
        startDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        diffDays++;
    }
    return diffDays;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## ThreeTen-Extra

The [Answer by Vitalii Fedorenko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23185006/642706) is correct, describing how to perform this calculation in a modern way with [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes ([`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) & [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html)) built into Java 8 and later (and [back-ported to Java 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and [to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)).

### `Days`

If you are using a number of days routinely in your code, you can replace mere integers with use of a class. The [`Days`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Days.html) class can be found in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project, an extension of java.time and proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. The `Days` class provides a type-safe way of representing a number of days in your application. The class includes convenient constants for [`ZERO`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Days.html#ZERO) and [`ONE`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Days.html#ONE).

Given the old outmoded [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects in the Question, first convert them to modern [`java.time.Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) objects. The old date-time classes have newly added methods to facilitate conversion to java.time, such a [`java.util.Date::toInstant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toInstant--).

```
Instant start = utilDateStart.toInstant(); // Inclusive.
Instant stop = utilDateStop.toInstant();  // Exclusive.
```

Pass both `Instant` objects to factory method for [`org.threeten.extra.Days`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Days.html).

In the current implementation (2016-06) this is a wrapper calling [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-), read the `ChronoUnit` class doc for details. To be clear: all uppercase `DAYS` is in the enum `ChronoUnit` while initial-cap `Days` is a class from ThreeTen-Extra.

```
Days days = Days.between( start , stop );
```

You can pass these `Days` objects around your own code. You can serialize to a String in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format by calling `toString`. This format of `PnD` uses a `P` to mark the beginning and `D` means “days”, with a number of days in between. Both java.time classes and ThreeTen-Extra use these standard formats by default when generating and parsing Strings representing date-time values.

```
String output = days.toString();
```

> P3D

```
Days days = Days.parse( "P3D" );
```

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates days between 2 date Strings:

```
    static final long MILLI_SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
    static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    public long daysBetween(String fromDateStr, String toDateStr) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Date fromDate;
    Date toDate;
    fromDate = format.parse(fromDateStr);
    toDate = format.parse(toDateStr);
    return (toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / MILLI_SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution that returns proper number or days between e.g. `11/30/2014 23:59` and `12/01/2014 00:01` here's solution using Joda Time.

```
private int getDayDifference(long past, long current) {
    DateTime currentDate = new DateTime(current);
    DateTime pastDate = new DateTime(past);
    return currentDate.getDayOfYear() - pastDate.getDayOfYear();
}
```

This implementation will return `1` as a difference in days. Most of the solutions posted here calculate difference in milliseconds between two dates. It means that `0` would be returned because there's only 2 minutes difference between these two dates.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Joda Time library because Java Util Date returns wrong values sometimes.

**Joda vs Java Util Date**

For example  days between yesterday (dd-mm-yyyy, 12-07-2016) and first day of year in 1957 (dd-mm-yyyy, 01-01-1957):

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse("12-07-2016");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Try with Joda - prints 21742
    System.out.println("This is correct: " + getDaysBetweenDatesWithJodaFromYear1957(date));
    //Try with Java util - prints 21741
    System.out.println("This is not correct: " + getDaysBetweenDatesWithJavaUtilFromYear1957(date));    
}


private static int getDaysBetweenDatesWithJodaFromYear1957(Date date) {
    DateTime jodaDateTime = new DateTime(date);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
    DateTime y1957 = formatter.parseDateTime("01-01-1957");

    return Days.daysBetween(y1957 , jodaDateTime).getDays();
}

private static long getDaysBetweenDatesWithJavaUtilFromYear1957(Date date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    Date y1957 = null;
    try {
        y1957 = format.parse("01-01-1957");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(date.getTime() - y1957.getTime(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

So I really advice you to use Joda Time library.

Comment: FYI, while [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) is still actively supported, its development team advises migration to [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html). To quote from their home page: “Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. Users are now asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310).”

Answer (score -6):

I did it this way. it's easy :)

```
Date d1 = jDateChooserFrom.getDate();
Date d2 = jDateChooserTo.getDate();

Calendar day1 = Calendar.getInstance();
day1.setTime(d1);

Calendar day2 = Calendar.getInstance();
day2.setTime(d2);

int from = day1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int to = day2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

int difference = to-from;
```

Comment: Do some testing on this, You will very quickly realise this will not work. Do from Dec 31 2013, to Jan 1 2014, Thats one day difference right? Your calculation will do,1 - 365 = -364. Which most certainly is not correct.