# Java date counting

Tags: java

I need to calculate the number of days passed between 2 dates using java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar and java.text.SimpleDateFormat. I'm breaking my brain, how could I accomplish that?

Comment: 1. Is this homework? 2. What have you tried?

Comment: `how could I accomplish that` - hardly

Comment: No guys I've done half of the task and I doubt that it would be effective to subtract current date from the date given using Calendar and than iterate until the year == 0 adding to the sum 365/366 days...

Comment: No indeed would anyone help after the previous two gentlemen wrapped the problem into the 'homework' paper?

Comment: Can you use JodaTime's Days.daysBetween?

Comment: I've used it and the solution was quite elegant, but I need to use only standard API.

Comment: java.util.Date is in UTS so a simple math like this will give you what you want int daysBetween = (endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime())/totalMillisecondsInADay

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an interview question, similar was asked to me in an interview 2 months back.

Well, here is another hint:
You have two dates. Java gives you time in millis for each date.
Say t1 and t2.

Without loss of generality we can assume t1>t2.
now t = t1-t2

divide t by 86400 * 1000  ( number of milliseconds in a day) and that is your answer :)