# Why does Java's Date.getTime() returns an incorrect response for January?

Tags: java, date

The code for calculating the date in milliseconds is:

```
//installment date converted to milliseconds
long localDateInstall = installDate.getTime();

//installment date converted to milliseconds
long localDatePay = payDate.getTime();
```

and here I calculate the number of days between these dates:

```
days=Math.abs((localDatePay - localDateInstall))/86400000;
```

When I want to test it, I enter `1/Jan/2012` for `localDateInstall` and `1/Feb/2012` for `localDatePay`. The result is: **29 Days**. What is the problem? Thanks

Comment: Might there be a daylight savings time adjustment between 1 Jan and 1 Feb in the timezone you used to map those dates to points in time?  In other words, was any day in Jan of 2012 in that timezone not 24 hours long?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3300078/20394 shows how to use Joda time to get the days between two dates.

Comment: `getTime()` only gives you the long timestamps from UTC [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime())

Comment: I agree with Mike. There is no reason why it should be giving you the wrong value. DST could be the only possible reason if you are doing everything right.

Comment: Daylight Saving Time (United States) began Sunday, March 11, 2012.  There's no change between January 1 and February 1.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Counter-example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
    Date installDate = format.parse("1 Jan 2012");
    Date payDate = format.parse("1 Feb 2012");
    long localDatePay = payDate.getTime();
    long localDateInstall = installDate.getTime();
    long days = Math.abs(localDatePay - localDateInstall) / 86400000;
    System.out.println(days);
}
```

This works fine, and the output is "31", as expected. The problem is somewhere in what you haven't told us. Shot in the dark: you're probably constructing your test input like this:

```
Date installDate = new Date(2012, 1, 1);
Date payDate = new Date(2012, 2, 1);
```

Sadly, that's wrong in two ways. First, the "year" argument is supposed to be "[the year minus 1900](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29)". Second, [January is month 0, not month 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int%29). With those two dates as input, you would, indeed, get an answer of 29 because you're actually asking it for the number of days in February of 3912, which is a leap year.

Comment: It's calculating the number of days in January, which shouldn't be affected by a leap year.

Comment: @phatfingers: Read what I wrote (the second half) again.

Comment: Whoops, quite right.  I retract my comment (and will upvote your entry).

Comment: @NargesSalehnia: That's not a very helpful comment. If this was the solution to your problem, please mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer. If not, please post your own answer explaining what the problem really was.

Comment: I'm doing this dateTimeString = "2014-12-03 04:25:00"`SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s", Locale.getDefault());
  
  Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateTimeString);
  
  startTimeInMillis = date.getTime();` date.getTime returning milliseconds that is Dec 02

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
//installment date converted to milliseconds
long localDateInstall=installDate.getTimeInMillis();

//installment date converted to milliseconds
long localDatePay=payDate.getTimeInMillis();

long diff = localDatePay-localDateInstall;

long diffInDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: How is that any different than what's already happening, aside from not taking the absolute value of the difference?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's enough information to go on, but here are some ideas to pursue.

1. You're performing integer arithmetic, which doesn't round, but rather truncates anything short of a whole day.  If your end time of day is even a little earlier in the day than your start time, you'll lose a whole day.
2. Make sure there isn't something funny going on with the time zones.  Are the two dates input in the same way, or are they coming from different sources which might have different time zones attached?
3. If you post the actual millisecond values for each, and your expected time zone, it should be pretty easy to determine which one of the two is off.