# Compute days between two dates in Java

Tags: java, date

I have a code that has 2 dates in the format

```
DateFormat dateFormat= new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
           Date date=new Date();

           DateFormat formatter ; 
           Date publishDate = (Date)dateFormat.parse(pubDate);
```

I want to calculate days between two dates. I can't use Joda package. Is there any way to get the day difference in the 2 dates ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use Joda package?

Comment: I have some restrictions. Is there any other way ?

Comment: Check answers here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java . The 4th is what you may need

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Date d1 = ..., d2 = ...;
long t1 = d1.getTime(),
   t2 = d2.getTime();
long day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // milliseconds in a day
return (t1 - t2) / day;
```

Comment: You need to **normalize** the `Date` objects millis by making them equal to the same point in the day; ex: 12AM for this approach to be 100% accurate.

Comment: it depends what the specifications are. But sure

Answer (score 1):

You can just subtract the millis between the 2 dates and then divide by number of millis per day

Comment: You need to **normalize** the `Date` objects millis by making them equal to the same point in the day; ex: 12AM for this approach to be 100% accurate.

Comment: And Daylight Wastings Time can affect the result too.

Comment: Yes, I was just giving a general idea of how to do it. There are definite issues with daylight savings times and other time oddities which make time difficult to deal with. My original thought would have been to just use JODA, but the OP said they cannot use it.