# Difference between 2 dates Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

I need to find difference between 2 dates. First one is in string format,

```
s1=2012-10-01T15:33:34.652905Z
```

I need to convert s1 into date d1 and then find the difference in integer between today's date d2 and d1.

How do I do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "difference"? Milliseconds? Days?

Comment: Take a look at [Joda Time API](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/).. Makes your life easy when working with Dates..

Comment: Days as in "hours / 24" or days as in "number of midnights between time A and time B in a given timezone?"

Answer (score 1):

To convert your string to a date, you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").

Given two Date objects, you can get whatever differences (days, seconds...) you need with [JODA Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) as advised in SO entry : [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)