# how to calculate difference between two dates using basic java

Tags: java

I just started going to university and basically just started using java and I want to know how to make a code that calculates the days between two dates but without the use of programs that take milliseconds and such things that I have seen in other answers.So this is the code I have created but it doesnt work perfectly it misses one day most of the times or something like that.Please I really need your help

Comment: When you say: "without the use of programs that take milliseconds and such things" do you mean "the really simple approach of taking the difference in milliseconds and dividing by the number of milliseconds in a day"? Additionally, is there any reason you want to write date/time code yourself instead of using a good API such as Joda Time?

Comment: Why can't you use the standard date methods? (Ninja'd by Skeet, I have been felled by a worthy opponent)

Comment: Guys, he just started out. Look at his ifs. Give him a break :)

Comment: I cant use those things because they do all the work themselves.I have to make the full code and use nothing but basic java like loops,if and things like that.The teacher even told us not using loops would be best but I cant come up with something without loops

Comment: I was looking for a difference() method in (Gregorian)Calendar to link him to, but looks like there's not one :-/

Comment: by the way I dont have to count the change of calendars which resulted into like 13 days plus

Comment: Give an example of one or more input values and what you expect as a result. Then go step by step (probably using a debugger) through your code to find out whats going wrong.

Comment: @Herminator I dont get what you did with the edit

Comment: The answer of your question is already given in the url
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351483/calculate-date-time-difference-in-java

Comment: okay I must make clear that I am inexperienced with java started using it like this month and I need more explaining providing that you have the courage and the mood to do that for me

Comment: So I guess that was all the help you guys could give to me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Nikoc You can click on the "edited xxxx hours / days ago" right next to your profile signature above to check the edits. My edit was done to improve the formatting of your source code, nothing else was changed. The edits have to be approved as well. Your last edit removed the entire source code (not sure why).

Answer (score 0):

Use a SimpleCalendar or GregorianCalendar classes...

but basing on what you posted, I'm unsure how to best suggest using those two... i'll draft a simple example shortly.

After some thought I'll just leave this here [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), `GregorianCalendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~gent0113/calendar/isocalendar_text5.htm

An approach could be to calculate the number of days from a fixed time for both dates and then just subtract those days. This will give you the difference of days between date 1 and date 2

The following method returns the number of days passed since `0 January 0 CE`

```
public int calculateDate( int day, int month, int year) {
  if (month < 3) {
      year--;
      month = month + 12;
  } 
  return 365 * year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + ((month+1) * 306)/10 + (day - 62); 
}
```

In you code now you should calculate the number of days since  0BC for both dates and then subtract them:

```
public void run() {
 ....

 int dayDifference = calculateDate(day1, month1, year1) - calculateDate(day2, month2, year2);

....
}
```

Comment: I dont really understand what the return is supposed to do and what I should delete from my current code in order to use the one you suggest.I also understand you are from Greece too

Comment: and btw it doesnt work unless I am doing something wrong.Doesnt calculate correctly for example I have inputted 08/12/1994 and 30/10/2012 and the daydifference shows 5985 but it really is 6536

Comment: You were right for the code, I was searching different option and mixed them, I edited the answer to have the correct code. For the part where to use it. Inside the run method you gather the input from the user and at one point you have ` int daydifference= 0;` now it should be `int dayDifference = calculateDate(day1, month1, year1) - calculateDate(day2, month2, year2);` then you only have to print the answer: `println("The days that have passed between those dates are " +daydifference);`.

Comment: I need you to explain what this parts does 


    public int calculateDate( int day, int month, int year) {
  if (month < 3) {
      year--;
      month = month + 12;
  } 
  return 365 * year + year/4 - year/100 + year/400 + ((month+1) * 306)/10 + (day - 62); 
}

Comment: I really dont know if I can use that formula to make my code.....seems like one of the programs that are used and get the day difference with no trying at all.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(
    LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) ,
    LocalDate.of( 2012 , Month.MAY , 17 ) 
)
```

> 55

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may change at any moment, so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Or specify a date. You may set the month by a number, with sane numbering 1-12 for January-December.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , 2 , 23 ) ;  // Years use sane direct numbering (1986 means year 1986). Months use sane numbering, 1-12 for January-December.
```

Or, better, use the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Month.html) enum objects pre-defined, one for each month of the year. Tip: Use these `Month` objects throughout your codebase rather than a mere integer number to make your code more self-documenting, ensure valid values, and provide [type-safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 1986 , Month.FEBRUARY , 23 ) ;
```

## `ChronoUnit.DAYS`

To get a count of days between two dates, call on the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum object [`DAYS`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#DAYS).

```
long days = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between( earlierLocalDate , laterLocalDate ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).