# Java Date handling

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

I want to calculate the number of days between two days and store all those dates in a date array. How can I do that. Please help me.

Comment: Why not try using google **before** posting? [Please read the FAQ on what questions should be posted here!](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Seems a fair enough question to me. this will make it easier http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html

Comment: you want to try `Joda date API` google for it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802893/number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jodatime

Comment: In Java 8+, `LocalDate.of( 2012 , 11 , 8 ).datesUntil( LocalDate.now() ).toArray( LocalDate[] :: new )`. See code run [at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/3LsZF1).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use a `Calendar` object with `Date` A and begin adding a day until you reach `Date` B. Every time you add a day store the modified date in an array.

Take a look here too: [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

PS: You should show us some code and some effort if you want a more complete answer.