# Date difference from current date in java

Tags: java

I am developing an application in JAVA swing, in that I wanted the date difference from current date like if today is `16/04/2013` then it should return `15/04/2013`. I have tried the following code:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
//if within the first 30 days, need to roll the year as well
if(cal.after(cal2)){
     cal.roll(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
}
System.out.println("Year " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println("Month " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
System.out.println("Day " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

In this code I was expecting to get one day back date. But instead I am getting  one month back date.
Ex. if today is `16/04/2013`, the expected output is `15/04/2013`, but I am getting  15/03/2013 ( one month one day back) as an output.

Comment: Are you obliged to use Calendar or would it be acceptable to use JodaTime?

Comment: try `cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);`

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java

Comment: Joda library stuns, I suggest it.

Answer (score 5):

You dont need any manual manipulations, Calendar will do all necessary date arithmetic automatically, simply do this

```
    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

Note that months in Calendar start from 0 so April is 3

Comment: `Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        System.out.println("Year " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println("Month " + cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println("Day " + cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));`                       this is what output im getting
        `Year 2013
        Month 3
        Day 15`

Comment: I added output to my test, it's 15 Apr 2013

Comment: Ah, got you, 3 is Apr, months start from 0 in Calendar

Answer (score 2):

That's a classic example why java.util.Date implementation sucks: Months numeration starts in zero:

```
0-> January
1-> February
2-> March
3-> April.
```

What you mean:

```
new Date(10,1,2013) //10th of January of 2013
```

What you get: 10th of February of 3983 (1970+2013)

Answer (score 0):

### tl;dr

```java
LocalDate.now().minusDays( 1 ) // Yesterday.
```

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

The classes `GregorianCalendar`, `Calendar`, `Date`, etc. are now legacy. These terribly flawed classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

### *java.time*

To represent a date only, without time-of-day & time zone, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Capturing the current date requires a time zone. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId ) ;
```

Get yesterday's date:

```
LocalDate yesterday = today.minusDays( 1 ) ;
```