# How I can find out difference of days between two dates in Java

Tags: java

Hi I have to find out days difference b/w two dates .First one is current date and 
second Date i am taking from database.Actually i want to send Automatic email at difference of 90 days b/w these two dates . Java 1.6 is using in my Application.

I am using this code

```
for(BidderHeaderBean checkBean:tenderheadersbean){
    Date currentdate=new Date();
    String datePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);
    String bidopeningdate=  MisUtility.convertDateToString(checkBean.getBidOpeningDate());
    Date givenDate = df.parse(bidopeningdate);
    Long last = givenDate.getTime();
    Long current=currentdate.getTime();
    Long timediff=last-current;
    Long diffdays=timediff/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

I am not getting difference of days.Please help me .
Thanks & Regards
Bhagwan singh

Comment: So, if not the difference in days, what are you getting?

Comment: Take the first date, transform it to a Calendar, add 90 days, see if the result is before or after the second date.

Comment: i am getting value of diffdays is -730163.

Comment: You know how the bid opening data has been established, and with which hour/minute/second value. - We all know that new Date() returns the current point in time. - We also know that a difference in milliseconds can be integer-divided by ms/day, and we can expect one day more or less, depending on the answers to previous questions. - So...?

Comment: Time increases: "now" has more milliseconds than any previous date.

Comment: Actually bid opening date is in "yyyy/MM/dd" format it's doesn't contain hour/minute/second value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably doing this the wrong way anyway, do a database query to give you every result where the difference is > 90 days.

Assuming you really need to do it this way (for example you've already loaded these records into Java anyway) then the correct way is to use a Calendar or the new java Time API to do all the maths for you. Take the first date, add 90 days to it, see if it is after or before the second date.