# Difference between two LocalDateTIme objects in days

Tags: java, datetime

I need to find difference between current dateTime `LocalDateTIme.now()` and  another `LocaDateTime` object called `issueDateTime` in number of days. Also days to be counted starting from the time in `issueDateTime`. That is, if `issueDateTime` is 12/04/2014 5:00 pm days should be counted as per 5 pm and not 12 am. I want to find the difference between issue date and current date in days and then multiply it with rentalTariff/day to return amount from method `amountPayable()`. thanks

```
public class RentOut {

private int rentalTariff ;
private LocalDateTime dateTime;
private String rentedTo;
private LocalDateTime returnDateTime;

public RentOut(int rentalTariff) {
    this.rentalTariff = rentalTariff;
}
public void RentIt(LocalDateTime dateTime, String rentedTo) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.rentedTo = rentedTo;
    this.returnDateTime = dateTime.plusHours(24);
}
public LocalDateTime getRentDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}
public LocalDateTime returnDateTime() {
    return returnDateTime;
}
public String getCustomerName() {
    return rentedTo;
}
public int amountPayable() {
  //return LocalDateTime.now().minus(dateTime)*rentalTariff;
}
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but complete example demonstrating the problem - just a simple console app with two `LocalDateTime` values, and how you're trying to solve the issue at the moment.

Comment: code added, have a look.

Comment: That's not a short but complete example, is it? It doesn't contain any sample data, and it has a bunch of unnecessary bits. A short but complete example in this case is likely to be a class containing just a `main` method with about three lines of code in...

Comment: Please clarify: is this Java 8, or Joda Time?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ChronoUnit.DAYS` for this. Compare the `LocalTime` values to see whether or not the start should be consider to be in "the next day":

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Start time before end time
        showDiff(2014, 9, 25, 15, 0,
                 2014, 9, 27, 17, 0);
        // Start time equal to end time
        showDiff(2014, 9, 25, 17, 0,
                 2014, 9, 27, 17, 0);
        // Start time later than end time
        showDiff(2014, 9, 25, 18, 0,
                 2014, 9, 27, 17, 0);
    }

    public static void showDiff(
        int startYear, int startMonth, int startDay,
        int startHour, int startMinute,
        int endYear, int endMonth, int endDay,
        int endHour, int endMinute) {
        LocalDateTime start = LocalDateTime.of(
            startYear, startMonth, startDay, startHour, startMinute);
        LocalDateTime end = LocalDateTime.of(
            endYear, endMonth, endDay, endHour, endMinute);

        System.out.printf("%s to %s is %d day(s)%n", start, end,
            differenceInDays(start, end));
    }

    public static int differenceInDays(LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime end) {
        LocalDate startDate = start.toLocalDate();
        LocalDate endDate = end.toLocalDate();
        if (start.toLocalTime().isAfter(end.toLocalTime())) {
            startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
        }
        return (int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2014-09-25T15:00 to 2014-09-27T17:00 is 2 day(s)
2014-09-25T17:00 to 2014-09-27T17:00 is 2 day(s)
2014-09-25T18:00 to 2014-09-27T17:00 is 1 day(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the day of the year from the `LocalDateTime` to calculate this. Take into account that the original date time could be after the current date if there is a difference in year. (which would result in negative results)

Comment: Day-of-year is likely to be inappropriate if it can span years... there are simpler approaches.

Comment: You could indeed use the Days class from Joda time to calculate the days between both dates as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java?rq=1.

Comment: There's no need to use Joda Time here. `ChronoUnit.DAYS` is the broad equivalent in Java 8.

Comment: Now you're taking the assumption that the OP uses Java 8. Since it was not specified I tried to answer in a way that works in most recent Java versions.

Comment: Yes, I've assumed that given that I'd expect Joda Time to be explicitly mentioned otherwise. (It's a third party library, vs JDK 8 which is just "the current version of Java.) Will ask for clarification though.

Comment: Since the source code provided by the OP already specifies the LocalDateTime I just assumed he forgot to mention that he works with that 3rd party library.

Comment: But Java 8 has `LocalDateTime` too. So there's nothing that uniquely specifies it here.