# Difference Between two dates in minutes - different months - Java

Tags: java, date, date-arithmetic

I want to find the difference in minutes between 2 dates. My code works well if the 2 dates are in the same month(and year) but it seems like the difference considers every month to be 31 days long so for the dates:

```
 2016-02-29 12:21
 2016-03-1 12:21
```

I get 4320 minutes or 72 hours

for:

```
 2016-04-30 12:21
 2016-05-01 12:21
```

I get 2880 minutes or 48 hours

my code where d1 and d2 are Date objects:

```
long getDateDiff(Date d1, Date d2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(); //in millisec
    long diffMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
    return diffMinutes;
}
```

Comment: A `Date` in Java just represents a point in time since the epoch, so if you want the difference between two dates as minutes, hours, or days, your current approach should work.  If you want difference in months, this will take more work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference in days between two dates in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299972/difference-in-days-between-two-dates-in-java)

Comment: Well would you look at that.  You just uncovered a bug that likely exists in all our applications at work.  Looks like I'll have to go file some tickets tomorrow morning.

Comment: Your date may be parsed or calculated incorrectly. The `getDateDiff` works for me except `timeUnit` is not used at all in the function. I get 1440 for both dates.

Comment: The code is fine private static long getDateDiff(Date d1, Date d2, TimeUnit timeUnit) {
  long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime(); //in millisec
  System.out.println("Diff in Seconds :"+diff);
  long diffHours = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff);
  return diffHours;
 }

Comment: According to your input you should get 24 hours and 24 hours but not 72 hours and 48 hours

Comment: Time zone? Are your example date-time values in UTC or some time zone?

Comment: How do you create your `Date` instances? I ask because `new Date(2016, 2, 29, 12, 21)` gives not the date you expect (the date you get is `3916-03-29 12:21`)

Comment: Very well spotted, @ThomasKläger. That would explain precisely the results reported. `Date` months are 0-based: January i month 0, so 2 is March, 3 April, 4 May and 5 June. Using these months in above calculations gives exactly 72 hours and 48 hours, respectively.

Comment: By the way, toiavalle, your method is not using its `timeUnit` parameter for anything.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is very weird with me. So I tried it:

```
    @Test
public void differenceDateTest() throws ParseException {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm");
    Date date = dateFormat.parse("2016-02-29 12:21");
    Date date2 = dateFormat.parse("2016-03-01 12:21");
    System.out.println(date2.getTime() - date.getTime());
    long mili = date2.getTime() - date.getTime();
    System.out.println(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(mili)); // 24 hours.
}
```

it returned exactly 24 hours.

Comment: I was creating the date wrong. Like @Thomas Kläger noticed

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

Parse your input strings.

```
LocalDateTime startLdt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-04-30T12:21" ) ;
LocalDateTime stopLdt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-05-01T12:21") ;
```

Assign the time zone or offset-from-UTC intended but omitted from the inputs. I assume you intended UTC itself (an offset of zero).

```
OffsetDateTime start = startLdt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime stop = stopLdt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time on the scale of days (24-hour chunks of time), hours, minutes, seconds, and nanoseconds.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop ) ;
```

> d.toString(): PT24H

Your first example results in 24 hours, as seen when [code runs live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/NN3OSA).

Your second example also results in 24 hours, as [seen in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/jjrVI9).

## Details

The Question and other Answers all use the troublesome old date-time classes or the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Both are supplanted by the java.time classes.

## Using java.time

Convert your `Date` objects to `Instant` objects, the equivalent in java.time. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant start = d1.toInstant();
Instant stop = d2.toInstant();
```

Use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) (or `Period`) for the span of time in between.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( start , stop );
```

Extract the total number of minutes across the entire span-of-time.

```
long minutes = d.toMinutes() ;
```

### Time zone

You do not mention the time zone intended for example date-time values. Is their context [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)? Or did you intend some particular time zone. In various time zones, anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means days are not always 24 hours long. So time zone is crucial.

Let's look at UTC.

```
// of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneOffset offset)
OffsetDateTime odtStart1 = OffsetDateTime.of ( 2016 , 2 , 29 , 12 , 21 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime odtStop1 = OffsetDateTime.of ( 2016 , 3 , 1 , 12 , 21 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
Duration d1 = Duration.between ( odtStart1 , odtStop1 );

OffsetDateTime odtStart2 = OffsetDateTime.of ( 2016 , 4 , 30 , 12 , 21 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
OffsetDateTime odtStop2 = OffsetDateTime.of ( 2016 , 5 , 1 , 12 , 21 , 0 , 0 , ZoneOffset.UTC );
Duration d2 = Duration.between ( odtStart2 , odtStop2 );

System.out.println ( odtStart1 + "/" + odtStop1 + " = " + d1 );
System.out.println ( odtStart2 + "/" + odtStop2 + " = " + d2 );
```

> 2016-02-29T12:21Z/2016-03-01T12:21Z = PT24H
>
> 2016-04-30T12:21Z/2016-05-01T12:21Z = PT24H

The string generated by `toString` is in standard [ISO 8601 format for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). The `P` marks the beginning, the `T` separates any years-months-days portion from any hours-minutes-seconds portion.

In both cases the **result is twenty-four hours. This is correct** because in each case you chose to go from the last day of one month to the first day of the following month. UTC has no anomalies, so we expect exactly 24 hours elapsed.

You can compare the `Duration` objects by calling [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#compareTo-java.time.Duration-). And you can do math to get the difference between them. In this case we expect a different of zero.

```
Duration difference = d1.minus( d2 );
```

> difference.toString(): PT0S

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/h4mwfN).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: The asker would still have to either create the `Date` objects correctly, using zero-based months, or better, avoid the old `Date` class altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I think order of date objects is not important, so I used `Math.abs()`

```
public long getMinuteDifference(Date date1, Date date2) {
  long millis = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());

  return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis);
}
```

This method returns 1440 minutes for your test cases which are:

```
Date d1 = convert(new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(2016, 4, 30, 12, 0, 0, 0));
Date d2 = convert(new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(2016, 5, 1, 12, 0, 0, 1));
assertEquals(1440, getMinuteDifference(d1, d2));

Date d3 = convert(new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(2016, 2, 29, 12, 0, 0, 0));
Date d4 = convert(new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(2016, 3, 1, 12, 0, 0, 1));
assertEquals(1440, getMinuteDifference(d3, d4));
```