# Getting days between current date and other date in Java

Tags: java, date, date-difference

I need a method which returns the difference in days between the current day and other any date, I have the following:

```
private long getDays(Date dateOp) {
    Calendar feCurrent=Calendar.getInstance();
    feCurrent.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    feCurrent.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    feCurrent.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    Calendar feAna=Calendar.getInstance();
    feAna.setTime(dateOp);
    feAna.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    feAna.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    feAna.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    feAna.getTime());
    long timeDiff = Math.abs(feAna.getTime().getTime() - feCurrent.getTime().getTime());

    return TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(timeDiff);
}
```

The thing is I'm always getting one day less, for example, if the date as parameter is Octuber 16th 2017, the result will 3, but it's actually four, I debugged and the timeDiff for those dates is 345599395 , when converted to days is 3.999....

Does anyone have idea why it's not working.

By the way the date as parameter is load from a database, because if I tried with a main setting both dates it works.

Comment: `feAna.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)`

Comment: Try to also set the milliseconds to `0` for both calendar instances. `cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)`

Comment: Also, this general method will fail if daylight savings starts between the two dates, because there'll be a day with only 23 hours, which messes up the division.

Comment: Note that `Calendar` and `Date` classes, which are part of the old date API, are legacy now. Instead use classes of the new API inside the package `java.time`.

Comment: Thanks, I put the milliseconds and it worked, I won't have issues with daylight savings because my country does not use them

Comment: @Alex Just because your country doesn't have daylight saving now, it doesn't mean it'll never have. DST is decided by governments and laws, and you can't guarantee that nobody will change this in the future. Anyway, if you just care about the dates without consider the time of the day, nor any DST effects, Szymon's solution with `LocalDate` works fine. But if you want to consider time of the day and DST, there's plenty of options in the possible duplicate I linked - specially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23185006/7605325) with `ZonedDateTime`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `java.time` components if you use Java 8

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

final class PeriodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.of(2017, 4, 4); // 2017-04-04
        LocalDate otherDate = LocalDate.of(2015, 10, 23); // 23-10-2015
        long days = Math.abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(otherDate, now));

        System.out.println("Days = " + days);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Days = 529
```

Pros:

- you don't have to play with old `Calendar` object
- you can convert `java.util.Date` to `java.time.Instant` with `Date.toInstant()` method to get it working with current example

#### Java 6 solution

For Java 6 you can use [`Joda-Time`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) that was a precursor of Java 8 Time API.

```
import org.joda.time.Days;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

final class PeriodTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.parse("2017-04-04");
        LocalDate otherDate = LocalDate.parse("2015-10-23");

        int days = Math.abs(Days.daysBetween(now, otherDate).getDays());

        System.out.println("Days = " + days);
    }
}
```

Comment: "the date as parameter is load from a database"

Comment: @Arkadiy `java.util.Date` can be converted to `java.time.Instant` easily with `Date.toInstant()` method.

Comment: Could you show the code to be used for  the date represented by a `Date` object, then? OP: " if I tried with a main setting both dates it works"

Comment: Thank you so much, I've used this previously but unfortunately this app works with Java 6, and it's restricted with external libraries, so only working with I have

Comment: @Arkadiy Added an example using `java.util.Date`

Comment: @Alex You can use `Joda-Time` then. It works with Java 6 and it was a precursor for Java 8 Time API

Comment: @Alex I've added an example using Joda-Time and no Java 8 Time API

Comment: Your edit broke this.  When you had `LocalDateTime`, this was correct, and handled daylight savings correctly.  When you changed it to `Date`, you made the daylight savings handling wrong.  I have removed my upvote.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Thanks for the comment, I haven't know that. The only problem is that Alex cannot use Java 8 solution anyway :/

Comment: Sure, but I'm thinking of people who encounter this question in the future, not just Alex.  Both your solutions are currently wrong.  If you're offering a Java 8 solution, I recommend making it an entirely Java 8 solution, including the use of `LocalDate`.  I don't know how to do this in joda-time, but I presume it must have something similar to `LocalDate` that you can use.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem You're right. I've reverted code example to `LocalDate`, same with `Joda-Time`. Alex could also try to replace `java.util.Date` with `Joda-Time` to avoid many problems.

Comment: Cool.  I've given you back my upvote.

Comment: For Java 6 and 7 you can use the [Threeten backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8  new datetime API. Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and even in [their site](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) there's a warning: *Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely "finished" project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to `java.time` (JSR-310)*. So, for new projects, it's better to use the backport.